# Using MassTransit + RabbitMQ is it possible to selectively retry contracts based on the contract's type?

Tags: masstransit

We use MassTransit with RabbitMQ.

There are [Exception Filters](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/exceptions#exception-filters) to ignore certain exceptions and not retry messages that cause those exceptions.

But is there a method to centrally configure this exception filtering based on the contract type at the bus level?

Here is an example consumer definition with exception filtering (At the consumer level)

```
public class GettingStartedConsumerDefinition :
    ConsumerDefinition<GettingStartedConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<GettingStartedConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r =>
        {
            r.Intervals(500, 1000);
            r.Ignore<ArgumentNullException>(); //do not retry ArgumentNullException 
            r.Ignore<MyException>(e => e.Mode == 2); //only do not retry MyException if mode is 2. All other MyException are retried
        });

    }
}
```

What I want is to filter based on contract type centrally, something like this

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
            // ... other code ...

            // list all the contracts that should not be retried
            x.Ignore<Contracts.GettingStarted>();
            // maybe with a condition ?
            x.Ignore<Contracts.GettingStarted2>(x=> x.Source == "Outside"); 

            });

        });
```

Comment: There isn't anything like this that can be globally configured.